# Error performing 'single click' on view 'matches 0th view.'

Tags: detox

Detox unable to perform the tap() and other actions when there are multiple matchers for an element. I am currently testing it on Android emulator Nexus_5X_API_27.

```
await element(by.type('android.widget.TextView')).atIndex(0).tap();
```

Also detox is unable to perform action for the matcher by.Type(), it asks for the fully qualified class name, so I used 'android.widget.TextView' for 'TextView' react-native element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a detox issue. It happens when detox unable to find the test ID. Can you check that you have declared the test id in child or Parent because in android it is considering the ids declared in Parent and it generally happens with react native components